# How do I decide amongst several prime lenses for fast-moving sports?

Tags: nikon, telephoto, sports, extreme-sports

I've already done a fair bit of research. I somewhat discarded the option of 70-200mm f/2.8 because of price and weight (I know I can get the new Tamron 70-200 g2 for about 1400 € but that's still too much and it weighs 1.5kg). It would probably get in my way when I move around in muddy terrain, over roots and rocks, in woods, on the beaches, etc.

*I don't plan to shoot football, basketball or other team sports, at least not yet and not with the lens I choose to buy at the moment.*

So I researched other options, and lots of people say they shoot 85mm f/1.8 or 105mm micro/macro lens. Or even wide lenses like 18-24mm when they can get sufficiently close to the subject, but this question is about telephoto lenses.

As such I identified a few lenses which are:

- Nikon Nikkor 85mm f/1.8g (500 €)
- Sigma 105mm f/2.8 EX DG OS HSM Macro (400 €)
- Nikon AF-S VR Micro NIKKOR 105mm f/2.8G IF-ED Lens (900 €)
- Tamron F017 N SP 90 MM f/2.8 Di Macro VC USD (650 €)

All of the above have great reviews on YouTube and between 4 and 5 stars on Amazon reviews.

I am an amateur photographer but still want to produce great quality shots for the sports niche I've chosen, which is mountain biking, cycling and other action sports.

Which one would be the best fit and is any one of them to be discarded? I heard comments about slow autofocus in general on macro lenses, is this still a big deal these days with these new lenses?

*Oh and btw, I only consider lenses with an aperture of f/2.8 or faster because of frequently shooting in woods.*

Comment: Before you go any further, are you absolutely sure that 100mm is enough?

Comment: I think you need a zoom, unless your style is to carefully pick a spot where you can shoot contestants as they come around a corner or cross a finish line, in which case a prime could work. If weight is a concern, how about using a monopod? If you can work around the weight, and if you can settle for a good used lens, you can surely find a used 70-200mm f/2.8 zoom for less than 900 €.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think it could be because in most mtb/cycling events one can get quite close to the track, I am talking anything from 2m to 10m and I have a crop body so there's some extra focal length because of that.

Comment: @canisbos not really fan of buying used but I could give it a try..you really nailed it with your "picking a spot" comment because more often than not that is the case, then when I'd switch my spot I could easily switch lenses too.. monopods, tripods are an option, maybe.

Comment: @mare I missed your point about needing to move over shifting terrain, which is hard enough when you're carrying no gear, much less a heavy camera and pro zoom! I now understand much better your considering a small prime like the 85/1.8G. That lens weighs hardly more than a 50mm. Unfortunately, it's also similar in autofocus speed to a 50mm, so perhaps not fast enough for sports/action.

Comment: can you post example of 2 pictures you personally like? Your question has quite a bit of range (starts with 200mm, ends with 18-24mm), there is no solution like that, that is also cheap and fast and light

Comment: You're not really asking *how* to decide, you're asking what your decision should be.

Comment: @Caleb On the “_how_ to decide”, that was my wording on the edit, not the OP’s. Take a quick look at the revision history. By all means, please edit it to make it better than I did. =)

Comment: @scottbb Your edit is the best thing about the question... *how* to decide would be on-topic, like [How to select lenses for outdoor sports photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/677/4262). But the point of this question seems to be *Which one would be the best fit and is any one of them to be discarded?*, which seems like a shopping question to me.

Comment: @Caleb The way I read it, is that the OP is showing their research work. I'm sure he would be open to other lens suggestions in his budget / performance specs. Also, to be fair (full disclosure), I had voted to close as Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Caleb and scottbb: Both of you are right in your opinions that this is/was a sort of shopping/opinion based question. In the few weeks that passed I had an opportunity to shoot again with my 18-140 3.5-5.6 kit lens (only in good enough in very good light), with 50mm (awesome if I am able to get close enough), 24-70 2.8 (also great if I'm close enough). I also saw that most of pros were actually using 70-200 2.8 and it indeed makes the best isolation/bokeh effect while still being very versatile.

Comment: Also I don't think I will be able to test any of the lenses mentioned above and I'm not buying one without being able to test it. I don't want the hassle of buying and then having to sell if it doesn't fit. I decided I will probably be better off going with 70-200 and don't reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: You have not described the shots you want to take well enough to recommend a lens.  How far are you from the action?  Can you predict where it will be?  What is the light level where you are shooting?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the sport that you're shooting.  Some sports let you get fairly close (e.g. hockey, curling, basketball); other sports require you to use long lenses at a distance (baseball, cricket, football/soccer, gridiron football).

Fast lenses are best because of the lighting conditions in some sports, especially indoor sports or games/matches played at night under stadium lighting.  Modern DSLRs give you more room for error on the ISO side of things than was the case in the film days, but a fast aperture will still help you shoot isolate the subject against the background, and let you use faster shutter speeds with higher quality.

Knowing the sport well, and knowing where to anticipate action, will help you considerably.

It's been awhile since I've shot curling or hockey, but when I did (as an amateur) I used a 35-135/3.5-4.5 (on 35mm film/full frame) and it was a pretty successful endeavour.  On the other hand, with gridiron football I used much longer lenses.  My 80-200/2.8 was my most useful lens (I lacked anything longer that was as fast) but I also got a lot of good use out of a modest 75-300/4.5-5.6.  In fact, my best football shot was shot with this lens, at the nearer end of the range, as a running back ran toward me on the sideline.  (Luckily he turned the corner.  :) )

Using what you have, and learning its limitations, will teach you more about what lens to add to your stable than any advice we have.  Go experiment and try, see how things turn out, and figure out what limitations you're running into - that will tell you what lens to get next.

Comment: I was looking exactly at the aperture.... If money is an issue, slower lens get cheaper way faster than "short" lens  (sigma has a 600mm f/5.6 for 1k US for instance). Personally, I'd make sure of the distances before anything, few things are worse than not being able to frame what you want from where they let you be :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Nikon 80-200mm f/2.8 AF-D ED Macro. Compared to the 70-200 you will get:

- (almost) the same optical quality
- pretty much the same weight, unfortunately
- No VR (not very usefull for sport anyway)
- A hugely better pricetag, especially used

It is not an AF-S lens, so it will only autofocus on bodies that have an AF motor.
https://kenrockwell.com/nikon/80200.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I currently own a crop body so no AF motor in it but worth to remember this lens if I ever upgrade to a body with motor.